# Just installed Ubuntu 10.10, can't connect via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall, virtualbox

I've just downloaded and installed Ubuntu 10.10 in a VM on virtualbox (4.0.4). Everything on the VM is set to the defaults: NAT adapter. When installing the OS, I selected OpenSSH, and nothing else.

I've tried to connect to the server via ssh from the host (running Mac OS X), but it only timeouts. Can't scp my credentials to it or ping the server either. As far as I can tell, the server is connected fine, has a valid IP, and can ping google.com.

I know I'm missing something basic here... I don't believe I have any kind of firewall up, unless there's one I don't know about that comes with the install. iptables has the default configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if ssh server is started and is listening on all interfaces, or on the interface you are coming from. Also change the adapter in VirtualBox from NAT to *internal network* or to *bridge*.

Comment: Changing the adapter to bridged did it. Looks like it was on a different subnet or something. Had an ip at 10.0.2.X before, now is 10.0.1.X. I'm not much of a network guy, so I'm not sure if there is a way to connect with that other IP. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that when you use VirtualBox NAT you are connecting from outside of the NAT. And because you are not able to punch holes in the VMware NAT you can not connect from the Host to the VM. To separate the VM from the physical network and to be able connect from the host to the VM you need to do a host only network and use the NAT from the Linux kernel.